# Error Cannot redeclare

Tags: php

Cuando intento entrar a mi pagina web para seguir con mi proyecto, recibo el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare selectValue() (previously declared in /home/admin/web/jobs.carinae-studios.com/public_html/rewrite/includes/functions.php:4) in /home/admin/web/jobs.carinae-studios.com/public_html/rewrite/includes/functions.php on line 4
```

Se que este error es causado cuando usas mas de una vez require o include, pero mi caso es muy extraño, ya que el dia pasado, todo estaba funcionando a la perfeccion, y al ir a cama y al despertar para seguir programando, empeze a recibir este error sin razon alguna. En todo mi codigo uso require_once, y nunca require o include a secas. Hay alguna solucion a este problema?, dejare una pequeña parte de mi codigo, ya que es muy grande.

index.php:1:22

```
<?php
require_once "includes/functions.php";
require_once "includes/settings.php";
require_once "includes/steamauth.php";

if(!isLogged()){
    header("Location: login/");
}else{
    require_once "includes/userInfo.php";
}

if(!userExists($_SESSION['steamid'])){
    header("Location: login/process_login.php");
}else{
    $lock = isLocked();
    if($lock == "true"){
        header("Location: ".$settings['domain']."lockscreen.php");
    }
}
require_once "includes/db.php";
require_once "includes/profile_functions.php";
?>
```

includes/functions.php:1:24

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

function selectValue($table, $value){
    require_once "db.php";
    $res = $conn->query("SELECT ".$value." FROM ".$table);
    if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            return $row[$value];
        }
    }
    $conn->close();
}

function selectValueWhere($table, $value, $where, $equals){
    require_once "db.php";
    $res = $conn->query("SELECT ".$value." FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$where." = ".$equals);
    if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            return $row[$value];
        }
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: El error no es por que uses `require` o `include` es por que estas definiendo 2 veces la misma función `selectValue()` por lo que cuando es llamada PHP es incapaz de saber a cual te estas refiriendo, en concreto parece que la tienes ya declarada en `functions.php` y en algun otro lugar.

Comment: No, estoy totalmente seguro que es el unico sitio en el que la tengo definida, y si asi fuera, entonces me diria en que archivo y linea esta definido por segunda vez

Comment: Revisa bien por que SI o SI esa función esta siendo incluida o declarada 2 veces en algun lugar, para evitar estas cosas se recomienda el uso de `namespace`

Comment: Ya he checado todos los archivos relacionados a index.php, y en ningun lugar declaro por segunda vez esta funcion. Lo que me parece extremadamente raro, es que en el transcurso de horas, el sistema dejo de funcionar de la nada, no habia hecho ningun cambio antes de que dejara de funcionar, todo fue en el transcurso de la noche (algo que me parece hasta imposible)

Comment: No se que IDE o editor usar pero muchos permiten hacer busquedas en todos los archivos del proyecto, esto permite localizar facilmente donde se esta defininfo un trozo de código mejor que mirando archivo por archivo.

Comment: Uso Sublime Text 3, tienes algun editor recomendado que pueda ejecutar tal funcion?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70956/discussion-between-xerif-and-roberth).